# recursive_wrapper and ambiguous convert_construct()

Tags: c++, boost, variant

Do you have any idea how to solve or get around this problem?

http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Variant-recursive-wrapper-and-ambiguous-convert-construct-td4543139.html

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
class b_fwd;
typedef boost::variant<boost::recursive_wrapper<b_fwd> > a;
class c_fwd;
typedef boost::variant<boost::recursive_wrapper<c_fwd> > b;

struct b_fwd : b {
  // inherit constructors
  template <typename... Ts> b_fwd(Ts... o) : b(o...) {}
};

typedef boost::variant<double, char *> c;

struct c_fwd : c {
  // inherit constructors
  template <typename... Ts> c_fwd(Ts... o) : c(o...) {}
};

void f(const b &b_node) 
{
    a a_node(b_node); 
}

int main() 
{
}
```

Comment: It would help if you posted the question here instead of just a link to it.  Also you should include your example code inline as well.

Comment: This is not exactly my question. I think it's rude to steal and repeat other peoples' questions without linking to the source. But it's my opinion.

Comment: That wasn't obvious from the question, so it looks like you asked the question somewhere else and then got lazy and just linked to it here instead of writing it out again.  If you do in fact have that selfsame question I see no problem copying it here.  If the plagiarism bothers you you can simply reword (and perhaps improve the indenting in the sample code while you're at it).

Comment: My guess is, looking the example, that boost supports constructing a variant from a variant with different types (probably as long as values are convertible).  This could cause problems if you try to create a variant that stores a variant (just like the example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a hunch in reaction to GuyGreer's comment.

If the problem is caused by variant being assignable/convertible to variant, then maybe we can disambiguate by using a third, isolated, variant:

```
a a_node(boost::variant<b>(b_node));
```

Lo and behold, homeopathy seems to work :)

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e68ec7963fd5646)**

<sub><sup>I have no idea whether this "works" in the sense that the OP expects, because, frankly, the OP's code was a mystery to me</sup></sub>

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
class b_fwd;
typedef boost::variant<boost::recursive_wrapper<b_fwd> > a;
class c_fwd;
typedef boost::variant<boost::recursive_wrapper<c_fwd> > b;

struct b_fwd : b {
    using b::b;
};

typedef boost::variant<double, char *> c;

struct c_fwd : c {
    using c::c;
};

void f(const b &b_node) 
{
    a a_node(boost::variant<b>(b_node)); 
}

int main() 
{
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't homeopathy involve diluting the (occurrences of) variants so much that there is less than 1ppm left in the code?

Comment: @GuyGreer I dunno, my source didn't mention this: http://www.howdoeshomeopathywork.com/

Comment: @sehe I have been using nested variant types before with variant-to-variant assignments. A similar problem appeared for me when I started assigning a types such as b_fwd to something like boost::variant<b_fwd,...>. Anyhow, your solution is very smart and magical to me haha. I don't understand how this does not cause compilation errors where 'a' expects a b_fwd whereas you are giving it boost::variant<b>.